# Change array key and value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my array

```
> Array ( [0] => width:960px [1] => padding:0px [2] => margin:auto [3]
> => position:relative )
```

and I need it to be

```
Array ([width] => 960px [padding] => 0px [margin] => auto [position] => relative)
```

This has been driving me crazy, if anyone can help with a solution that I would be really grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Loop over each data, explode() it on the ':' character, set the first part to the key, the second part to the value

Comment: Tried explode but did not have the assocArray outside my foreach loop *smacks head* Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by simply looping through your array and splitting it at `:`.

```
$associativeArray = array();
foreach( $indexedArray as $element ) {
    list( $key, $value ) = explode( ':', $element, 2 );
    $associativeArray[ $key ] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/explode) to split your string, and then add it to a new array.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($your_array as $value) {
    list($css_key, $css_value) = explode(':', $value);
    $new_array[$css_key] = $css_value;
}
```

Note: caution should be taken when doing this so you don't overwrite your array keys (e.g. if you had multiple lines like `width: 600px` etc

Comment: How could I prevent this being overwritten?

Comment: You should nest your arrays so they look like this: `array( 0 => array('width' => '600px'), 1 => array('width' => '650px'))` etc

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is

```
$assocArray = array();
foreach ($indexedArray as $v)
{
    $key = substr($v, 0, strpos($v, ":"));
    $value = substr($v, strpos($v, ":") + 1);
    $assocArray[$key] = $value;
}
var_dump($assocArray);
```